# Unstick folks: what's the meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation

What's the meaning of the expression "unstick folks", in this context? A guy, who "prides himself on being able to **unstick folks**", is helping another person with a computer trouble.

Comment: If it has a meaning that should be something like *To solve people's problems, particularly by getting them out of a situation in which they're stuck…* but that's deductive reasoning.

Having worked with computers for nearly 30 years and four or five of them in technical support, when I spoke to at least several hundred thousand users I have never once noticed that phrase in speech or writing.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a negation of the specific definition of *stuck* below.

> [unstick](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unstick)
>   verb (used with object), unstuck, unsticking.
>   1. to free, as one thing stuck to another.
>   verb (used without object), unstuck, unsticking.
>   2. to become unstuck:
>   *Finally, the car's horn unstuck.*
>   (Dictionary.com)
>
> [stuck](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stuck)
>
> 7. adjective
>      If you get stuck when you are trying to do something, you are unable to continue doing it because it is too difficult.
>      • *They will be there to help if you get stuck.*
>      • *If he gets stuck on a word, he can make the computer prompt him.*
>      Synonyms: baffled, stumped, at a loss, beaten
>
> (Collins)

Here *folks* is the object of *unstick*. So if they (the folks) have a computer problem and they become stuck (= baffled, unable to progress), then he is able to help them with hints or solutions. In that sense, he *unsticks* them. They are no longer baffled and they are able to proceed in the problem or onto another problem. He prides himself on this ability.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the adjective in your example

> unstick

is used as the present tense of

> unstuck

so to

> unstick folks

is someone who helps people

> become **unstuck**
>   He helps people *become unstuck*.

which is how it is usually phrased.